# when writing spock test in groovy java mixed project unable to resolve class

Tags: groovy, gradle, classpath, spock

java8 gradle2.3 groovy2.4.3

```
 sourceSets {
        main {
            java { srcDirs = [] }    // no source dirs for the java compiler
            groovy { srcDir "src" }  // compile everything in src/ with groovy
        }
        test{
            java {srcDirs = []}
            groovy{ srcDirs = ["src/test/java", "src/test/groovy"] }
        }
    }
```

ControllerServiceSpec.groovy: 18: unable to resolve class org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc

```
import info.thecodinglive.controller.TeamController
import info.thecodinglive.service.TeamService
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.spockframework.runtime.Sputnik
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc
import spock.lang.Specification
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.setup.MockMvcBuilders.*
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.*

@RunWith(Sputnik)
class ControllerServiceSpec extends Specification{

    def teamController = new TeamController()
    def teamService = Mock(TeamService)

    MockMvc mockMvc = standaloneSetup(teamController).build()

    def setup(){
        teamController.teamService = teamService
    }
```

dependency

```
 {compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.3'
  testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version:'4.12'
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test', version:"$springVersion"
    testCompile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-test-mvc', version:'1.0.0.M1'
    testCompile  "cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1"
    testCompile('org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4') {
       exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy"
    }
```

it works compile groovy/java but when i test controller
can't find dependencies

Comment: Why do you manipulate the source sets? Just apply `groovy` plugin (it applies `java` automatically) and set the default structure: src/main/java, src/test/java, src/main/groovy/, src/test/groovy.

Comment: Cause i made groovy class then other java class reference groovy class

Comment: I doesn't matter. Try what I wrote in the previous command and it should work well.

Comment: That's  a point if i don't mixed it work  i've already knew

Comment: Sorry, don't understand :/ It this project available on the web?

Comment: Why are you messing with the `srcDirs`?  I believe this is the root of your problem

Comment: Tim Cause first run javacompile task then groovyCompile  i want to groovy instance referencing in java class so just passed javacompile task and  groovycompile task run at that time work groovy clas loader and java class loader